# Perl tests - getting compilation warnings but test still stubornly show that everything is OK

Tags: perl, testing

I get this when I run the test, but as you can see, both tests still show OK. I don't like this at all. How do I turn the warnings into errors?

```
1..2
Allowing a native trait to automatically supply a default is deprecated. You can avoid this warning by supplying a default, builder, or making the attribute required at UserInfo.pm line 7
        require UserInfo.pm called at (eval 4) line 2
        main::BEGIN() called at UserInfo.pm line 0
        eval {...} called at UserInfo.pm line 0
        eval 'package main;
use UserInfo @{$args[0]};
1;

;' called at /packages/run.64/perl-5.14.1/lib/5.14.1/Test/More.pm line 885
        Test::More::_eval('package main;\x{a}use UserInfo @{$args[0]};\x{a}1;\x{a}', 'ARRAY(0x16fa110)') called at /packages/run.64/perl-5.14.1/lib/5.14.1/Test/More.pm line 860
        Test::More::use_ok('UserInfo') called at UserInfo.t line 7
ok 1 - use UserInfo;
ok 2 - require UserInfo;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn warnings into errors? Here you are!

```
use warnings FATAL=>"all";
```

If you want the script not to just die, but to fail specific tests, you can add this to the above:

```
use Test::Exception; 

# later
lives_and {
     is ($this->value, 42);
} "Value is 42 (and no warnings)";
```

See [Test::Exception](http://search.cpan.org/~adie/Test-Exception-0.31/lib/Test/Exception.pm).

Yet another way (as I stated in comment below) is defining a warning pseudo-signal handler:

```
my @warn;
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { push @warn, shift; };

# later
ok (!@warn, "No warnings were emitted");
```

Comment: `use warnings FATAL=>"all";` is not enough.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: `eval` must be blocking the exception here. I don't know a good way to get around this, perhaps, a hack like `my @warn; $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {push @warn, shift; };` and then `ok (!@warn)`. This can be overridden in the module however.

Answer (score 3):

Deprecated features still work, but signal to you that they will disappear. Stop using the deprecated featured to get rid of the warning.

To test that your code runs with no warnings, try [Test::NoWarnings](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-NoWarnings).

Comment: Huh? So `Test::More` is deprecated? What is the replacement?

Comment: Did you look at Test::NoWarnings before panicking? :)

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using `$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { warn $_[0]; die };`

This will force the test to report an error even in case of an warning and still print the warning itself.

Comment: Why warn? Just use die. You'll stop the program and still get the error message. However, Dallaylaen gave you several better options.

Comment: @brian No you won't get the error message if you just use die.

Comment: Well, you die with the message you want to print. You don't need the warn. Read the docs on die. Read the docs on anything before you make further statements.